# Preloading images that are loaded via CURL

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am loading a large amount of facebook profile images using the Facebook SDK which uses curl.

I am trying to use a loading animation that is displayed until the images have loaded.

As the images are loaded via curl and therefore still load after the document is ready, I'm not sure how to go about this?

Comment: are you talking about these http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asa

Your results from curl can be / might even be set in an array.  You can loop that array, into a javascript array as page loads, when curl finishes, javascript can take over and load each image from the array and as loading a wait image can be loaded in its place. "that is how i swap loading image for object."